# React JS : Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

There are many instances of this error on Stack Overflow but sadly nothing that has aided in debugging the issue. I'm trying to run my web application on localhost and when the browser opens I'm getting `Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>` in the following line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/main.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Main />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Main.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Switch,Route, Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/store.js';
import JobListing from './job_listings/joblisting.js';
import JobPostings from './JobPostings/JobPostings'
import CustomJobApply from './JobApply/customApply.js';
import EasyJobApply from './JobApply/easyApplyModal.js';
import Jobs from './JobApply/jobs.js';
import JobsApplied from './JobApply/jobsApplied.js';
import ListAllConnections from './networks/listallconnections';
import ShowConnectedUsers from './networks/showconnectedusers';
import Login from './applicant/login'
import UserProfile from './applicant/userprofile'
import UserVisit from './applicant/uservisit'
import UserProfileFirst from './applicant/profilefirst'
import {history} from './../util/utils';
import Navbar from "./navbar/Navbar";
import Search from "./Search";
import UserListing from './applicant/userlistings';
import ApplicantDashBoard from './applicant/applicantDashBoard';
import RecruiterDashBoard from './applicant/recruiterdashboard';
import CityApplications from './applicant/citywiseapplication';
import DeleteAccount from './applicant/deleteapplicantaccount';
import LineChartExample from './applicant/linechartexample';
import UserSearch from './applicant/usersearch';
import ResumeView from './applicant/resumeview';
import ApplicantHome from "./feed/applicantHome.js";
import Resumes from "./JobApply/resumes.js";
import Messages from './messages/messages.js';
import RecruiterDashboard from './RecruiterDashboard/RecruiterDashboard';
import RecruiterJobsDashboard from './RecruiterJobsDashboard/RecruiterJobsDashboard';
//import PieGraph from './graph/pie.js';

class Main extends Component {
    render(){
        localStorage.setItem("counter",0)
        localStorage.setItem("HALFFILLEDRECRUITER","")
        localStorage.setItem("HALFFILLEDJOBTITLE","")
        localStorage.setItem("RECRUITERNAME","");
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/listings" component={JobListing} />
                <Route exact path="/userlisting" component={UserListing} />
                <Route exact path="/postjob" component={JobPostings} />
                <Route exact path="/customapply" component={CustomJobApply} />
                <Route exact path="/mynetworks" component={ListAllConnections} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/easyapply" component={EasyJobApply} />
                <Route exact path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
                <Route exact path="/jobs/applied" component={JobsApplied} />
                <Route exact path="/navbar" component={Navbar} />
                <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
                <Route exact path="/profilefirst" component={UserProfileFirst} />
                <Route exact path="/userprofile" component={UserProfile} />
                <Route exact path="/uservisit" component={UserVisit} />
                <Route exact path="/deleteapplicantaccount" component={DeleteAccount}/>
                <Route exact path="/applicantDashBoard" component={ApplicantDashBoard}/>
                <Route exact path="/recruiterdashboard" component={RecruiterDashBoard}/>
                <Route exact path="/usersearch" component={UserSearch}/>
                <Route exact path="/resumeview" component={ResumeView}/>
                <Route exact path="/feed" component={ApplicantHome} />
                <Route exact path="/recruiter/dashboard" component={RecruiterDashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/recruiter/myjobs" component={RecruiterJobsDashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/mynetwork/connections" component={ShowConnectedUsers} />
                <Route exact path="/messages" component={Messages} />
                <Route exact path="/citywiseapplication" component={CityApplications} />
                <Route exact path="/linechartexample" component={LineChartExample} />
                <Route exact path="/resumes/:userid/:filename" component={Resumes} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default Main;
```

I noticed that I haven't include any `<NavLink>` in my code. What might be wrong?

Comment: Where is any `NavLink` component being rendered? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]? What is `Main` rendering?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the reply, I added Main.js . But as i meantioned in the post. Im not using ```NavLink``` anywhere.

Comment: Somewhere in the current route, a `NavLink` must be getting rendered. Maybe try removing code until you can narrow down where.

Comment: It looks like the `Main` component is importing RRDv5 components, i.e. `Switch` and another `Router`. Make sure you are using all `RRDv6` components and a single router, and fix all the `Route` components to use the correct props & syntax. Somewhere in the app a `NavLink` component is being rendered. `Main`'s `render` function also shouldn't be setting localStorage as an unintentional side-effect, use `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` for this.

Comment: Thanks. will try for sure!. What do you mean by "fix all the Route components to use the correct props & syntax"

Comment: RRDv6 `Route` components have no `exact` or `component` props. See [Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) for the type declaration. You might want to also look over [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) to review other breaking changes.